# Base of V contains a base of Ker f and a base of Imf

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If we have a linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$, where {$x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$} is a base of Ker $f$ and we complete this base such that $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a base in $V$, how we can prove that $\{f(x_{k+1}), f(x_{k+2}), \ldots, f(x_n)\}$ is a base in Im $f$? Where Im $f$ is the image of function $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ be the basis of $V$. To begin with let's prove that $Im(V)=Lin{(L(v_1),...,L(v_n))}$
$a_1L(v_1)+a_2L(v_2)+...+a_nL(v_n)=L(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n)=u$
By definition what makes the image of L are the vectors u for which there exists a vector s such that $L(s)=u$, so the statement holds.
Now if vectors $v_1,v_2...v_k$ belong to the kernel then $L(v_1),...,L(v_k)$ and their linear combinations are mapped to $0$. That leaves the remaining $Lin{(L(v_{k+1}),...,L(v_n))}$ to span the image. And since $dim(Ker(L))+dim(Im(L))=dim(V)$ and we have $n-k$ vectors then it is also the smallest linearly independent set which makes it the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n\}$ is a spanning set of $V$, the set
$$
\{f(x_1),\dots,f(x_k),f(x_{k+1}),\dots,f(x_n)\}
$$
is a spanning set for the image of $f$. However, $f(x_1)=\dots=f(x_k)=0$, so also $\{f(x_{k+1},\dots,f(x_n)\}$ is a spanning set for the image of $f$.

By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\operatorname{im}f=n-k$, so the set has to be a basis.

If you can't use the rank-nullity theorem, directly prove that the set is linearly independent: if $\alpha_{m+1}f(x_{m+1})+\dots+\alpha_nf(x_n)=0$, then
$$
\alpha_{m+1}x_{m+1}+\dots+\alpha_nx_n\in\ker f
$$
and it's easy to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$V/Ker(f) \cong Im(f)$.

Then completing your basis in the way you mentioned, what is a basis for $V/Ker(f)$? Then, consider how the above isomorphism is given.